# Is there documentation on all the available keys under vueCompilerOptions in tsconfig.json?

Tags: vue.js

On https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar they mention something about vueCompilerOptions. And I just learnt in annother Github issue that I can turn the strictTemplates: on for Vue under that options. But interestingly there is no page I can find on the internet that documents all the available options. Can someone give me a pointer? A link to the relevant source code is also fine.

Comment: find in the vue repo

Comment: the list: https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools/blob/master/packages/language-core/lib/types.ts#L31  I don't know what they all do though.  You could further search the source code or maybe make a [discussion](https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools/discussions/categories/q-a) post on the github asking the devs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some information in this part of the source code here: https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools/blob/0f5dfcec3365518c4edb0c0b32397597786ca0e1/packages/language-core/schemas/vue-tsconfig.schema.json#L28